# A button that shows how long time it gets pressed

Tags: java, android, button, time

I wanna make a button that can show me how long time it gets pressed. If the button stops to get pressed the time still stays there, then you can keep pressing it. How can i do this?

With this code, I made a 5 second button-press open a new activity :)

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     final Handler handel = new Handler();
        button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {



        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            switch (arg1.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                handel.postDelayed(run, 5000/* OR the amount of time you want */);
                break;

            default:
                handel.removeCallbacks(run);
                break;

            }
            return true;
        }

        Runnable run = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {


                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecActivity.class);
                 startActivity(i);

            }
        };});

}}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: Try to use `onTouchListener` and capture `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`. You need to play with them to understand and achieve the functionality.

Comment: Yes i understand that i need to use: OnTouchListener. But i doesnt quite know how to code this.

Answer (score 1):

if your mean a Button count the times it's pressed you can use:

```
int count = 0;
   (your button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            count++;
        }
    });
```

if you mean the longer you hold it you can use:

```
long time = 0;
    (your button).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(event.getAction() == event.ACTION_DOWN){
                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }else if( event.getAcion() == event.ACTION_UP){
                time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

note: that your variables like (int count) and (long time) should be declared in the body of your class not into a method;

below code is a example code for recognizing double click on a view with Custom time;

```
boolean isPressed = false;
long delayed = 1000;
final Hanlder handler = new Handler();
Button b;
b.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        if(isPressed == true){
            // recognize double click;
        }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"tap again to exit",1).show();
        isPressed = true;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                isPressed = false;
            }
        },delayed);
    }
});
```

Comment: Here's what i got so far: http://gyazo.com/b21c2a461858559e9cd460b4e770a8e4 I don't know how to make a timer that counts the time I press the button. Can you help me? I'd appreciate an answer :)

Comment: Your link is unavaible

Comment: Ok, now i have posted in the question when i have doen so far. I've made a 5 second button-press open a new activity. What i want to make it, is to count the seconds i press the button. Help :)

Comment: You mean when you press it it srarts counting the time and stops it when you release it??. By the way i wrote all situation i guess you need

Comment: Yes thats what i mean. Im kind of a newbiee so i doesn't understand how I will make it work with your codes.. Do I need a textView to show me the numbers? Could you like, try to edit my code into what i want the button to do? Or just explain? Thanks :)

Comment: see, my first code is to count the times Button is pressed. my second code is to count the duration between pressing and releasing and my last code is to make a double click with a custom delay seconds. I cannot get you well. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try TouchListener:

Handler handel = new Handler();
    b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        switch (arg1.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            handel.postDelayed(run, 5000);
            break;

        default:
            handel.removeCallbacks(run);
            break;

        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Later define run:

Runnable run = new Runnable() {

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // Your code to run on long click

}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Set a listener for when the button is pressed and when the button is released. Create a timer that records after the button is pressed and stops when the button is released. There should be listeners for both if you are using JFrame or Android as your GUI.